# toHaveValue returns null while the input's value is 0

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, jest-dom

I'm working on a test code for my React project. What I want to check is 'if the input type is number, it disallow the text insertion'. Below is the test code I wrote.

```js
it("disallow a text input", () => {
  const input = screen.getByLabelText(label0); // it has 0 as initial value
  const dummyText = "imyourfather";

  // typing a text won't change the value of input
  userEvent.type(input, dummyText);
  screen.debug();
  expect(input).toHaveValue(0); // FAILED -> return null
});
```

What I've expected here is to get the initial value, `0`, as a result of `toHaveValue`. But it actually returns `null`.

You might think 'yes, you tried to insert a text to a number-typed input, that's why it returns null', but the funny thing is that `debug()` and `console.log(input.value)` return `0` as I expected.

```html
<!-- the result of debug() -->
<div
  class="ui input"
>
  <input
    id="form-field-number01"
    required=""
    type="number"
    value="0"
  />
</div>
```

And also if you manually try to insert a text value to a number-typed input on browser, it actually shows the initial value, 0. Anyone knows why `toHaveValue` and `debug` are showing different results?

Comment: As you can see from your own debug log the initial value is not `0` but `"0"`. It's a string, not a number

Comment: @lbsn even when everything works well and returns the integer `0`, it shows you `"0"` on `debug()`'s result, because it is written in a html form.

and even if the actual result is `"0"`, it doesn't make sense you get `null` as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, it appears this is indeed an expected behaviour of `toHaveValue` in case of `<input type="number">`.

First of all, the input value when you enter a string (in case of `type="number"`) is actually an [empty string](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type=number)):

> The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the
> element is not a valid floating-point number, then set it to the empty
> string instead.

While `screen.debug()` will output the DOM tree, you can check the actual `value` property by logging it after your dummy text has been typed:

```
userEvent.type(input, dummyText);
console.log('--> Value: ', input.value);
console.log('--> Value type: ', typeof input.value);
```

Now, the function used by jest-dom to get the input value looks like [this](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/blob/d24b6be0c43d0cc9ca192d1fa6fbfb790c3e8b86/src/utils.js#L189):

```
function getInputValue(inputElement) {
  switch (inputElement.type) {
    case 'number':
      return inputElement.value === '' ? null : Number(inputElement.value)
    case 'checkbox':
      return inputElement.checked
    default:
      return inputElement.value
  }
}
```

As you can see, in case of `type="number"` an empty string gets resolved to `null`. Not sure what's the reason behind this.

As for your specific case you could test the input element to not have your dummy text as a value or to have an empty displayed value:

```
expect(input).not.toHaveValue(dummyText);
expect(input).toHaveDisplayValue("");
```

Comment: wow. I haven't even cared about the input's spec itself. such a nice explanation. thanks a lot :)